# various ways and their runtime to check if a path exists between two nodes or vertices?

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, disjoint-sets

I have seen articles in SO and elsewhere, where the following methods are cited for determining if a path exists between two nodes in a graph. I would like to know if any one is better than the other?

1. Breadth First Search - `O(V + E)`
2. Depth First Search - `O(V + E)`
3. Using [disjoint sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) - `O(n log n)` (not sure if it is `O(n log n)`)

Does all these methods work for directed and undirected graphs, cyclic as well as acyclic?

Any preference for one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I can definitely answer about linear time algorithms - BFS, DFS should work for all types of graphs (directed/undirected, cyclic/acyclic).
Think about it : starting with given node they will visit *every* edge and every node *maximum* once so they are not affected by cycle(s).
 They will do it in a different fashion, BFS - "*level-by-level*", DFS - in a kinda greedy labyrinth-escaping manner, but they both will either terminate at some point (path exists), or after traversing all edges and visiting each node, they will terminate with negative result.
"Directivity" only affects what nodes are *reachable* from given node A, but implementation of algorithm(both bfs and dfs) is ignorant about whether graph directed or not.

I am not sure that *union-find* structure (your last item with disjoint sets) will help you in case of directed graphs.
Afaik, `Union-find` will put (*merge*) nodes `a` and `b` in one set if they are mutually reachable, i.e. there is a path from both `a` to `b` and vice versa.
If you have edge `a -> b` between `a` and `b`, and no other path leading from `b` to `a`, in that case according to *Union-find* data structure will not be able to put them not in one set.
,
but obviously  path `a` -> `b` exists.

Comment: I did not understand your union-find explanation especially "Again, just applying simple logic : if you have edge 'a -> b' between 'a' and 'b', and no other path leading from 'b' to 'a', in that case according to Union-find data structure they are not in one set.
, but obviously path 'a' -> 'b' exists."

Comment: @user1988876 I updated my explanation, hope it is more clear now. Please, check with exact union-find implementation as I only put my idea that it does not work on `directed` graphs, but I am not super-sure about that. I AM super-sure about bfs & dfs though.

Comment: you are right. union-find might not help in directed graphs. can you look at this  SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060357/dijktra-algorithm-vs-breath-first-search-for-shortest-path-in-graph

Answer (score 1):

BFS is better than DFS, as it finds the **shortest** path [so you can stop the algorithm quicker].

Do not know much about disjoint sets (will read about it shortly) and probably update my answer. [from what I read it seems to be more complicated than BFS, as it is used to find all components of the graph].

One of options not mentioned by you is to consider bidirectional BFS -- so running BFS from start and end simultaneously and stop once both searches meet. It will be inefficient though, if it is rather likely that no path exists and -- in case of cyclic graphs -- it could be implemented only if you keep references to both incoming and outgoing edges.

For sure: BFS and DFS work on undirected, directed, cyclic and acyclic.

If you want you can play with them a bit [here](http://grzesiaka.home.pl/GraphTutor/).

Comment: What do you mean when you say bi-directional BFS would be inefficient if no path exists? Like BFS and DFS, it would just visit all nodes and then finish, theoretically using less memory too. As for keeping references to nodes we've already visited in cyclic graphs, we'd need to do that for standard BFS and DFS too. So I don't understand what you mean by these two comments in regards to bi-directional BFS.