# Dijktra algorithm vs breath first search for shortest path in graph

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, breadth-first-search

I need some clarifications and inputts regarding `Dijktra's algorithm` vs `breath first search` in directed graphs, if these are correct.

`Dijktra's` algorithm finds the shortest path from Node `A` to Node `F` in a `weighted` graph regardless of if there is a cycle or not (as long as there are no negative weights)

but for that, All paths from `A to all other Nodes in the graph are calculated and we grab the path from`A`to`F`by reversing the sequences of nodes in`prev`.

BFS: finds the shortest path from `Node A` to `Node F` in a non-weighted graph, but if fails if  a cycle detected.

however, `BFS` just calculates the path from Node A to Node F and not necessarily all path from Node A.
if Node F is reached early, it just returns the path.

[image]

Comment: Maybe a better topic for [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: @user2573153: read the first line

Comment: _BFS: finds the shortest path from Node A to Node F in a non-weighted graph, but if fails if a cycle detected._ No, it is not correct. (Why you think, it fails?)

Comment: @arturgrzesiak: you are correct. BFS should work for cycles too. will DFS work too?

Comment: @user1988876 I think Sebastian has provided correct answer. To summarize : 1. BFS works with cycles too, as artur pointed out. 2. In non-weighted graph (i.e. all edges have equal weight) `Dijkstra` will visit nodes in `exactly same` manner and order as `BFS` and stop at the same time, so in that case they are kinda "equivalent"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dijkstra doesn't search all nodes of the graph. When it has found a way from A to F and is sure there is no shorter one (because the outer border of the already visited nodes is farther away), it stops. This is possible without negative weights.

So to answer your question "if these are correct": They are not.

Comment: First of all: Dijkstra's finds shortest paths from a chosen node to all other nodes in the graph. I cannot see, how it can be -- easily -- modified to stop earlier. Could you provide an example? (Just would like to remind that we are considering **weighted** graphs)

Comment: @arturgrzesiak: Intially, I was under the same impression as you. But I have modified my code, to check if my destination node is arrived, if it is, I just return and collect the prev path from it. Since, Dijktra is greedy, what you have got is already optimal for that path.

Comment: Just read the wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm. It's there in the second paragraph: "paths from a single vertex to a single destination vertex by stopping the algorithm once the shortest path to the destination vertex has been determined". On such well known algorithms as this one, Wikipedia is pretty reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Those algorithms are quite different in terms of their execution.

BFS is a kind of brute-force algorithm that follows a "static execution pattern" 
Dijkstra on the other hand is more dynamic and continues its search always at the point with the lowest cost.

The purpose of dijkstra is to find the shortest path. So if you are looking for the shortest path use dijkstra.